# Disassembler running on windows

Tags: software-development

I am looking for a disassembler (preferably free) that can meet the following requirements:

- I would like to have it so that I can specify say, a C source file, and the disassembly can map to different lines of code in the source. That way, I can see assembly representation of my functions.
- Can run on Windows 8 and 8.1. (is Windows 10 to early to ask about)
- This one is optional, but it would be nice to see Visual Studio 2013 / 2015 integration.

Does anyone know of a disassembler that would fit these requirements? Again, it would be preferable if it were free, but paid is ok as well.

Comment: Visual Studio itself does this. See [How to: Use the Disassembly Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3cwf295.aspx)

Comment: If it's not your own code, meaning that you don't have the link map, then don't expect much. You certainly won't get the original variable names, nor the exact source code (complex statements may be split into multiple simpler statements). Much depends on the level of compiler optimization used when generating the executable.

Comment: What have you already tried. Google reveals a lot of help, much of it on http://stackoverflow.com/  What is wrong with @Greg's statement that you would need something else?

Comment: And don't forget to browse the new beta site http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/  for instance, see questions/1817/is-there-any-disassembler-to-rival-ida-pro

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Comment: The Telerik decompiler only decompiles .Net assembly's to C# / VB.Net / MSIL and does not disassemble to pure assembly

Answer (score 1):

Install the gcc compiler tool chain, e.g. for Windows the MinGW toolchain, then use the following:

```
> gcc -g -c test.c
> objdump -d -M intel -S test.o
```

Note that with this tool chain you can even specify that you would like to compile for.

- Free
- Definitely works on Win8.1 if it doesn't work on 10 it soon will
- You can use this from within VS by putting it in a bat file & specifying it as an external tool.